# Codechef Factorials wrong answer

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, factorial

So I am working on small factorials in code chef. I get the correct answers when I test the program. Though when I submit it I get wrong answer. So I figured fresh eyes could help. here is a link to the problem https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2 
and then here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class FactorialTestDrive {

    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int t, n, fact;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        do {
            t = input.nextInt();
        } while (t < 1 && t > 100);
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            do {
                n = input.nextInt();
                fact = 1;
            } while (n < 1 && n > 100);
            for (int l = n; l > 1; l--) {
                fact = fact * l;
            }
            System.out.println(fact);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe your code is not accepted for performance reasons. General an optimal factorial solution is made through recursion

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the definition for `Fac(n)` is `n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*1`, and all you would need is a single loop for that, perhaps two at most.  Why do you have three loops here?

Comment: @apomene Actually, I have gotten nailed too many times in interviews to count, for using recursive solutions that would not scale for very large inputs.  But maybe it would make sense here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The first loop is the number of test cases you want to do. The do loops are to make sure that the numbers are within the range its asking for and the first for loop is to count up the test cases and the last for loop is to do the factorial.

Comment: @apomene what do you mean by optimal ? unless you are using a functional language or a (excellent) compiler, a recursive implementation might cause the stack to grow way too large. it might be optimal from a readability point of view, but from a performance/memory point of view, i think a `for` loop is the best choice.

Comment: @davidowens please fix the code formatting.

Comment: Maybe you're violating the max source-length condition of 2000 characters? I see nothing in the challenge that says you will be thrown junk inputs that you have to weed out, so those `do...while` validation loops around the  inputs are unnecessary code that could be counting against you.  I'd get rid of them.  And that TODO comment as well...

Comment: You're getting wrong answer because a factorial increases exponentially. For example 15! is clearly out of range of ints. So, better use BigInteger and memoization to store the values you've already calculated

Comment: Use [Big int](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/biginteger-class-in-java/) class as @rafid059 mentioned. Refer [this](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/16352892) solution for reference.

Comment: @rafid059 you was right on it so thanks for that. Now the problem is exceeding time limit here is the new code!

Comment: @rafid059    import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;
class FactorialTestDrive {
 private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 private static int t,n;
 private static BigInteger f = new BigInteger("1");
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  t = input.nextInt();
  for(int i = 0; i < t; i++){
   n = input.nextInt();
   fact(n);
  }
 }
 public static void fact(int x){
  for(int l = x; l > 1; l--)
  {
   f = f.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(l));
  }
  System.out.println(f);
 }
}

Comment: That is out of the scope of this question. But I'll answer it here anyway. Let's say you calculate the factorial of 7 which is 7*6*5*4*3*2*1. Now let's say you calculate the factorial of 8. It will be 8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1. But wait! That's basically 8*7!. If you could save the value of 7! you previously calculated, then you could've used it to calculate the value of 8!. Right now, your code calculates 7! every time it's asked to calculate 8!. So, you need some way to store the values you calculated previously. This method is known as memoization. Google it up and read up on it. Good luck!